# How is it possible to use core data without writing SQL?

Tags: ios, sql, core-data

I am new to using core data. I tried to find the answer to my question elsewhere and wasn't able to. My question is this: I've been working with core data a bit and using it in apps that can read and update a database, but I'm doing this without writing SQL. How is that possible?

Comment: There are many different software packages in C, Java, et al that allow you to access a SQL database without writing SQL statements.  SMOP.

Answer (score 0):

Core Data is a framework for storing data in your app. It uses SQLite in the backend, but the API abstracts it away from you so you don't have to use SQL queries.

You can learn more about Core Data from Apple's [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTechnologyOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009296-SW1).